# How to automatically select or deselect the all child nodes whenever its parent Node is selected or deselected in Excel-VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Automatic select/deselect parent checkboxes of a Treeview of Excel-VBA.

I have a code with me from the following sources:

1. https://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=48560&lngWId=1
2. http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?249131-VB-Check-All-Treeview-Children

Assuming Treeview as Treeview1, I have combined both of them and made my code.

```
Private Sub TreeView1_NodeCheck(ByVal Node As MSComctlLib.Node)
    Call CheckChild(TreeView1, Node) 'perform check on child nodes
    'CheckChildren Node 'Call subroutine
End Sub


Private Sub CheckChild(Tree As TreeView, CurrentNode As Node)
    Dim ParentIndex 'used to find out the index of the parent node from the child node that was clicked
    Dim CheckChecked As Integer 'Used to decide whether or not parent is to be checked
    Dim j As Integer 'Counter
    On Error Resume Next

    If CurrentNode.Checked = True Then 'If node is checked then check parent node ONLY if ALL child nodes are checked
        If Tree.Nodes.item(CurrentNode.Index).Checked = True Then 'If "My Node"(My Node's Index) is checked then
            ParentIndex = Tree.Nodes.item(CurrentNode.Index).Parent.Index 'locate index of parent node
            For j = 1 To Tree.Nodes.item(ParentIndex).Children 'run loop to find out which child nodes
                If Tree.Nodes.item(ParentIndex + j).Checked = False Then 'are checked and which are not...

                    CheckChecked = CheckChecked + 0 'unchecked and 1 for checked, add to
                ElseIf Tree.Nodes.item(ParentIndex + j).Checked = True Then 'previous value  
                    CheckChecked = CheckChecked + 1
                End If
            Next j

            If CheckChecked = Tree.Nodes.item(ParentIndex).Children Then 'if the number of checked nodes is equal
                Tree.Nodes.item(ParentIndex).Checked = True 'to number of child nodes then all child
            Else 'nodes are checked so check parent node
                Tree.Nodes.item(ParentIndex).Checked = False
            End If
        End If
    ElseIf CurrentNode.Checked = False Then 'if the current node is unchecked then
        ParentIndex = Tree.Nodes.item(CurrentNode.Index).Parent.Index 'uncheck the parent node as ALL child nodes
        Tree.Nodes.item(ParentIndex).Checked = False 'must be checked to before the parent node is checked
    End If

    'To enable and disable checkboxes based on Parent Node CheckBox
    Dim i As Integer, nodX As Node
    If CurrentNode.Children <> 0 Then 'If node has children
        Set nodX = CurrentNode.Child 'Catch first child
        For i = 1 To CurrentNode.Children 'Loop through each child
            nodX.Checked = CurrentNode.Checked 'Set as checked
            'CheckChildren nodX 'Check to see if this node has children
            Set nodX = nodX.Next 'Catch next child
        Next 'Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm expecting a minimal code.

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next` otherwise you cannot see any errors. This line hides all error massages but the errors still occur. If you cannot see them you cannot fix them. Remove that line and check if you get any errors. Fix them.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something similar. This should work for your case. It works because the first child node will always be at the index after the current node. The recursive function will return the index of the next child after it has worked its way through the rest of the children.

This will only work if you load the nodes in as they appear in the tree.

```
Private Sub TreeView1_NodeCheck(ByVal Node As MSComctlLib.Node)
    CheckChildAndGetNextIndex Node,Node.Checked
End Sub

Private Function CheckChildAndGetNextIndex(currentNode As Node, val as boolean) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    currentNode.Checked = val

    CheckChildAndGetNextIndex = currentNode.index + 1

    For i = 1 To currentNode.Children
        CheckChildAndGetNextIndex = CheckChildAndGetNextIndex(TreeView1.Nodes(CheckChildAndGetNextIndex), val)
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar solution to Tyson's, but without the need to reference the Treeview object (which makes it universal) and without a need to return an integer (which can cause overflow problems if you have many many nodes).

```
Private Sub tvSubcategorias_NodeCheck(ByVal node As MSComctlLib.node)
    TreeView_SiblingsAndChildren_Check node.child, node.Checked
End Sub

'Iterates through the node's children and all of it´s next siblings
Private Sub TreeView_SiblingsAndChildren_Check(node As node, Checked As Boolean)
    Do
        If node Is Nothing Then Exit Do
        'Do what you gotta do here
        node.Checked = Checked
        
        'Do this same routine with the first child node (if exists)
        If node.Children > 0 Then TreeView_SiblingsAndChildren_Check node.child, Checked
        Set node = node.Next 'Next sibling
    Loop
End Sub
```